# How to document the functionality in C++20 modules?

Tags: c++, module, documentation, c++20

When providing a library to others, documentation of e.g. class member functions can be included in the header files which contain the declarations. If properly formatted, this documentation can also be interpreted and displayed by IDEs.
Using C++ modules, how can I pass on information about the functionality in the module without falling back to external documentation, e.g. Doxygen? I assume comments do not make it as such into the compiled interface file?

Comment: Why do the comments need to be in the BMI any more than they need to be in an object file?  You aren’t supposed to give your users *only* a BMI.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, this question is actually pointless. I thought that - unless provided with the complete source code - libraries would be provided completely in binary format when using modules. Although the idea of deploying just one library file without additional files has its charme.

Comment: I’m sure someone will try it, but BMIs are not expected to be compatible across compilers or even versions, so it’d be a mess.